# How to re-configure mouse buttons on Linux?

Tags: scroll, mousewheel, xinput

I want to re-configure mouse settings so that I could scroll up and down when I click the middle button on my mouse (wheel).

I typed the `xinput --list` command in the terminal and got the following output:

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:16                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:16              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:16                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

What was strange that there were no mouse or keyboard in the list. Is there any way to achieve my goal?

OS: Fedora 31.